# Update default value of site column and update lists with REST

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, site-column

I want to change the default value of a site column and update all lists that contains that site column, with the new default value.

I already found how to change the default value with REST API, but I cannot find how to update all the lists with the new default value. This is the code I use for updating default values:
[image]

I already tried 'Update':true but I get the following error:

> The property 'Update' does not exist on type 'SP.FieldText'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type

Answer (score 0):

The Field type in the SharePoint Client Object Model has a method named `updateAndPushChanges` that commits changed properties of the field and optionally propagates changes to all lists that use the field. However, it appears that this method has not been implemented in the SharePoint REST API.

[SP.Field.updateAndPushChanges Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj244946(v=office.15))

[image: SP.Field.updateAndPushChanges Method]

You could look at using the Microsoft Graph to make changes to the site column. The update operation for `columnDefinition` resource type appears to support propagation of changes.

[Update columnDefinition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/columndefinition-update?view=graph-rest-1.0)